# Chat client - Socket and server socket concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

So for a project I am making a little peer to peer, two person chat client using Java in the Netbeans IDE.

My question isn't exactly code but more about structure and how to implement.

What I want to do is have the client open and have a `ServerSocket` listening for any connections that are trying to be made from another client using a `Socket` (This other client is also supposed have a `ServerSocket`)
So the idea is that both clients have the ability to accept a connection once the client is opened and have the ability to try and make a connection.

Anyway, the issue is that `ServerSocket.Accept();` blocks (Correct terminology?) the program once it is called until the time-out finishes. What I want is that the `ServerSocket` just listens in the background for any incoming connections and connects them if so, without disabling the function of the program entirely(i.e. the user being able to initiate connection themselves) while this occurs?
To do this do I need to create a separate thread for the `ServerSocket`, which is killed once the connection has been made?

Also, once the connection has been made, how do I get the program to periodically check the input stream of the `Socket` to see if there are any incoming messages from the other client?

Is there a way I can achieve this in a single thread? (I haven't really delved into threads yet)

I'm sorry if this is a bit broad.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Don't be afraid of using multiple threads. As soon as you do something with Swing or AWT you will have multiple threads anyway. So don't "run away" from threads - try to "tame" them ...

Comment: Would you be able to point me to somewhere that explains threads? I think that is the best way to do what I want here.

Comment: The tutorials I used for learning in 1997 are no longer online. I would have to search the web again. The pages by Angelika Langer and also the ones by Lars Vogel are a good start for searching for good java related information and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerSocket blocks and that's it.

But if you only want peer-to-peer communication between two connected parties and nothing more then this behavior is not a problem. You just need two programs: server and client. Server block until it gets connection from client and client blocks until it gets connection.

If you want to implement Java IO in single thread you should use Java Nio. There are lots of tutorials for that in internet. For example http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/server-socket-channel.html.

Also it seems that you are not very familar with networking and sockets so it might be beneficial to use some layer instead of raw sockets.

Maybe you should consider JeroMQ (https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) for implementing communication between programs.

Comment: Also, what is JeroMQ, I cant seem to find anywhere that explains it.

Comment: In programming layer is abstraction that hides low level implementation details and possibly offers some more functionality. In this case if you only want working peer-to-peer chat it might be easier to use some high level library instead of using raw sockets.

Comment: JeroMQ is pure java implementation of ZeroMQ (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all). Purpose of ZeroMQ is to provide more higher level abstraction of communication than raw sockets do.

Comment: Hmm ok, so SocketChannels from NIO? Or something like that? Is that what you were referring to? Or is there another I could use?

Comment: Yes. If you want to learn efficient low level communication using Java then  SocketChannels & co are way to go.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I will look into JeroMQ and multithreading.